# why does (complement a union complement a) gives a itself?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Why isn't it just complement a itself? I've tried searching google and nothing really came up. I tried this on Wolfram ALpha.

EDIT: Nevermind, Wolfram was right and gave 'complement' and I didn't notice the little sign in front of the a.

Comment: What did you type on WolframAlpha?

Comment: Please take anything Wolfie A tells you with a grain of salt.

Comment: Do you mean "(complement a) union (complement a)" or do you mean "complement (a union complement a)"? Not that you're going to get "a itself" either way.

Comment: (complement a union complement a). The output looked like boolean algebra notation, while (complement a union complement b) would give me a venn diagram, so IDK if there would be a difference.

Comment: @bof: The first statement. Can you explain why the first statement wouldn't result in 'a complement'?

Comment: (complement a) union (complement a) = complement a, not "a itself".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I entered "complement a union complement a" verbatim: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=complement+a+union+complement+a

The result is $\neg a$, which is again the complement of $a$.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean $A' \cup A'$? If so, then this does indeed equal $A'$. Essentially because the uniom of any set and itself is itself.

If you instead meant $(A \cup A')'$, then you would just be taking the compliment of the universal set, which is the empty set.